# Recovering probability distribution from binary observations - what are the reasons for the defects of this implementation?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I am trying to recover a probability distribution (not a probability density, any function with range in [0,1] with f(x) encoding probability of success for a observation at x). I use a hidden layer with 10 neurons and softmax. Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random
import math

#Make binary observations encoded as one-hot vectors.
def makeObservations(probabilities):
    observations = np.zeros((len(probabilities),2), dtype='float32')
    for i in range(0, len(probabilities)):        
        if random.random() <= probabilities[i]:
            observations[i,0] = 1
            observations[i,1] = 0
        else:
            observations[i,0] = 0
            observations[i,1] = 1
    return observations

xTrain = np.linspace(0, 4*math.pi, 2001).reshape(1,-1)
distribution = map(lambda x: math.sin(x)**2, xTrain[0])
yTrain = makeObservations(distribution)

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

x = tf.placeholder("float", [1,None])
hiddenDim = 10

b = bias_variable([hiddenDim,1])
W = weight_variable([hiddenDim, 1])

b2 = bias_variable([2,1])
W2 = weight_variable([2, hiddenDim])
hidden = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(W, x) + b)
y = tf.transpose(tf.matmul(W2, hidden) + b2)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, yTrain))
step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.2, step, 1, 0.9999)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(rate)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=step)

predict_op = tf.argmax(y, 1)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(50001):
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={x: xTrain})
    if i%200 == 0:
        #proportion of correct predictions
        print i, np.mean(np.argmax(yTrain, axis=1) ==
                     sess.run(predict_op, feed_dict={x: xTrain}))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ys = tf.nn.softmax(y).eval({x:xTrain}, sess)
plt.plot(xTrain[0],ys[:,0])
plt.plot(xTrain[0],distribution)
plt.plot(xTrain[0], yTrain[:,0], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

Here are two typical results:
[image]
[image]

Questions:

What is the difference between doing `tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, yTrain))` and applying softmax manually with minimizing cross entropy?

It is typical for the model not to snap to the last period of the distribution. I've had it do so successfully only once. Perhaps it will be fixed by doing more training runs, but it doesn't look like it as the results often stabilise for the last ~20k runs. Would it most likely be improved by better selection of the optimising algorithm, by more hidden layers, or by more dimensions of the hidden layer? (partially answered by Edit)

The aberrations close to x=0 are typical. What causes them?

**Edit**: The fit has improved a lot by doing

```
hiddenDim = 15
(...)
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.5)
```

and changing the activations to tanh from sigmoids.

[image]

Further questions:

Is it typical that a higher hidden dimension makes braking out of local minima easier?

What is the approximate typical relation between the optimal dimension of hidden layers and dimension of inputs `dim(hidden) = f(dim(input))`? Linear, weaker than linear or stronger than linear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's over-fitting on the left and under-fitting on the right.

Because of the small random biases your hidden units all get near zero activation near `x=0`, and because of the asymetry and large range of the x values, most of the hidden units are saturated out around `x = 10`.

The gradients can't flow through saturated units, so they all get used up to overfit the values they can feel, near zero.

I think centering the data on `x=0` will help.
Try reducing the weight-initialization-variance, and/or increasing the bias-initialization-variance (or equivalently, reducing the range of the data to a smaller region, like `[-1,1]`).

You would get the same problem if you used RBF's and initializad them all near zero. with the linear-sigmoid units the second layer is using pairs of linear-sigmoids to make RBF's.